# Are inline styles bad?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, styles, inline

React's *Styling and CSS* documentation attempts to answer the question [*Are inline styles bad?*](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-styling.html#are-inline-styles-bad) with a brief suggestion that "CSS classes are generally better for performance than inline styles". But no further explanation is offered.

Strictly from a performance perspective, and politely ignoring the obvious cost of shipping duplicate CSS declarations, how bad exactly are inline styles compared to CSS?

Answer (score 0):

I think inline styling not bad always but most of time it's better not to use inline style because of these following reason:

1. it's overwrite the other style you use in CSS file for that element
2. can't use custom responsive style in CSS file for that element
3. if you use a style in many tags and you want to change it you must change all of them but if you use a class it cost only change the class style

Comment: Thanks Hamed, your points are true, but I am really looking for an answer that focuses on performance differences specifically.

Answer (score 0):

I also add that for me it's the most inconvenience: performance.
Inline styles make your pages more big so that bandwidth and load time grow up and affect also on SEO.

Comment: Thanks, Carles, but I was hoping just to focus on performance, _except_ for the bandwidth cost of duplicate CSS declarations which I am already familiar with. I would love to know if there are other factors with inline styles that affect page load time...